# Adding a variable number of hashes to an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I have an array of hashes. Some of the hashes look like this:

```
hash1 = 
{8=>#<BigDecimal:7f19980a1938,'0.3313035E5',18(27)>}
```

some look like this:

```
hash2 = 
{3=>#<BigDecimal:7f19980a0100,'0.416158182E5',18(27)>,
 6=>#<BigDecimal:7f1998083870,'0.451966284E5',18(27)>,
 7=>#<BigDecimal:7f1998083208,'0.487774386E5',18(27)>}
```

and others look like this:

```
hash3 = 
{1 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998066e78,'0.680865408E5',18(27)>,
 2 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998066950,'0.680898708E5',18(27)>,
 3 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998066428,'0.680932008E5',18(27)>,
 4 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998065e60,'0.680965308E5',18(27)>,
 5 =>#<BigDecimal:7f19980658e8,'0.680998608E5',18(27)>,
 6 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998065348,'0.681031908E5',18(27)>,
 7 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998064998,'0.681065208E5',18(27)>,
 8 =>#<BigDecimal:7f1998064358,'0.681098508E5',18(27)>,
 9 =>#<BigDecimal:7f199805bb90,'0.681131808E5',18(27)>,
 10=>#<BigDecimal:7f199805b550,'0.681165108E5',18(27)>,
 11=>#<BigDecimal:7f199805afb0,'0.681198408E5',18(27)>,
 12=>#<BigDecimal:7f199805aa88,'0.681231708E5',18(27)>}
```

I want to loop through the array with these hashes and make sure each hash has 12 keys. If a hash has `n < 12` keys, `12-n` keys should be added to the hash, namely `n+1`, `n+2`,...,`n=12`. All of these added keys should have values that are empty strings.

For example, `hash1` should become:

```
{1=>"", 2=>"", 3=>"", 4=>"", 5=>"", 6=>"", 7=>"",
 8=>#<BigDecimal:7f19980a1938, '0.3313035E5', 18(27)>,
 9=>"", 10=>"", 11=>"", 12=>""}
```

and `hash2` should become:

```
{1=>"", 2=>"", 3=>#<BigDecimal:7f19980a0100,'0.416158182E5',18(27)>,
 4=>"", 5=>"", 6=>#<BigDecimal:7f1998083870,'0.451966284E5',18(27)>,
 7=>#<BigDecimal:7f1998083208,'0.487774386E5',18(27)>,
 8=>"", 9=>"", 10=>"", 11=>, 12=>""}
```

I am trying to loop through the array to create a table that looks something like this:

```html
<table border="border">
  <thead>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      January
    </th>
    <th>
      February
    </th>
    <th>
      March
    </th>
    <th>
      April
    </th>
    <th>
      May
    </th>
    <th>
      June
    </th>
    <th>
      July
    </th>
    <th>
      August
    </th>
    <th>
      September
    </th>
    <th>
      October
    </th>
    <th>
      November
    </th>
    <th>
      December
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Seed</th>
    <td>26.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>25.43</td>
    <td>28.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>23.23</td>
    <td>255.23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Planting</th>
    <td>26.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>26.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>25.43</td>
    <td>28.23</td>
    <td>25.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>27.23</td>
    <td>23.23</td>
    <td>255.23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can you show me how to do this or let me know of a better way?

#### Edit:

I edited the table above to better reflect what I am looking for.

Here is what I have to work with:

```
hash4 =
{
  "seed" => {8 => # < BigDecimal: 389 c1e8, '0.3313035E5', 18(27) >
},
  "planting" => {8 => # < BigDecimal: 3896 fb8, '0.33936408E5', 18(27) >
},
  "tilling" => {8 => # < BigDecimal: 3896220, '0.35029368E5', 18(27) >
},
  "weed_spray" => {4 => # < BigDecimal: 38959 b0, '0.38035008E5', 18(27) >
},
  "fertilzer" => {3 => # < BigDecimal: 3894 c68, '0.416158182E5', 18(27) >,
                  6 => # < BigDecimal: 388 bde8, '0.451966284E5', 18(27) > ,
                  7 => # < BigDecimal: 388 aee8, '0.487774386E5', 18(27) >
                 },
  "water" => {12 => # < BigDecimal: 388 a420, '0.51116373E5', 18(27) >
},
  "power" => {1 => # < BigDecimal: 38895e8, '0.5150061675E5', 18(27) >,
              2 => # < BigDecimal: 3888828, '0.518848605E5', 18(27) >,
              3 => # < BigDecimal: 387 fb10, '0.5226910425E5', 18(27) >,
              4 => # < BigDecimal: 387e d78, '0.52653348E5', 18(27) >,
              5 => # < BigDecimal: 387 da68, '0.5303759175E5', 18(27) >,
              6 => # < BigDecimal: 387 cb90, '0.534218355E5', 18(27) >,
              7 => # < BigDecimal: 386 b7a0, '0.5380607925E5', 18(27) >,
              8 => # < BigDecimal: 3869 fb8, '0.54190323E5', 18(27) >,
              9 => # < BigDecimal: 3869158, '0.5457456675E5', 18(27) >,
              10 => # < BigDecimal: 3867808, '0.549588105E5', 18(27) > ,
              11 => # < BigDecimal: 3866 c50, '0.5534305425E5', 18(27) >,
              12 => # < BigDecimal: 3865 d78, '0.55727298E5', 18(27)>
             },
    "labor" => {11 => # < BigDecimal: 3864 a68, '0.55775115E5', 18(27) >
},
    "harvesting" => {5 => # < BigDecimal: 385 ff68, '0.56458215E5', 18(27) >,
                     6 => # < BigDecimal: 385 f5b8, '0.57141315E5', 18(27) >,
                     7 => # < BigDecimal: 385e ac8, '0.57824415E5', 18(27) >
                    },
    "loan_repay" => {1 => # < BigDecimal: 382 f318, '0.680865408E5', 18(27) >,
                     2 => # < BigDecimal: 382e918, '0.680898708E5', 18(27) >,
                     3 => # < BigDecimal: 382 ddd8, '0.680932008E5', 18(27) >,
                     4 => # < BigDecimal: 382 d428, '0.680965308E5', 18(27) >,
                     5 => # < BigDecimal: 382 caa0, '0.680998608E5', 18(27) >,
                     6 => # < BigDecimal: 3823 c20, '0.681031908E5', 18(27) >,    
                     7 => # < BigDecimal: 3823130, '0.681065208E5', 18(27) >,
                     8 => # < BigDecimal: 3821380, '0.681098508E5', 18(27) >,
                     9 => # < BigDecimal: 38204 d0, '0.681131808E5', 18(27) >,
                     10 => # < BigDecimal: 3813460, '0.681165108E5', 18(27) >,
                     11 => # < BigDecimal: 38122e0, '0.681198408E5', 18(27) >,
                     12 => # < BigDecimal: 38115 c0, '0.681231708E5', 18(27) >
   }
```

}

Comment: One reason that there is been little interest in your question is that you have not taken the time to reduce the question to its essentials. It is absurd, for example, to present such an enormous hash (that I named `hash4`. btw, it's helpful to always assign inputs in examples to variables so that readers can refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them), when you could make the point with a hash that is the fraction of that size. Many SO members tend to skip over questions that are not concise and to-the-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just write a helper method like this, which accept your incomplete hash and return 12 key hash in proper order

def prepare_hash(incomplete_hash)
    sample_hash, result_hash = {}, {}
    (1..12).to_a.each do |val|
      sample_hash[val] = ""
    end
    sample_hash.each do |key, val| 
      result_hash[key] = incomplete_hash.has_key?(key) ? incomplete_hash[key] : val
    end
    puts result_hash
    result_hash
  end
prepare_hash(hash1) # => {1=>"", 2=>"", 3=>"", 4=>"", 5=>"", 6=>"", 7=>"", 8=>"<BigDecimal:7f19980a1938,'0.3313035E5',18(27)>", 9=>"", 10=>"", 11=>"", 12=>""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is named "ary"

```
   ary = [{},{},{}]
   ary.each_with_index {|hash, index| puts "#{index} is missing params" if hash.count != 12}
```